Get root folder for BIM360/ACC project (Autodesk)
Is there any solution to get project root folder without :hubId?
I know :projectId and want to get its root folder.
I didn't find any endpoints or methods for this witout :hubId.
I try to create recursive fetch for /parent endpoint but this is not the good approach i guess.

There is no way to determine the parent folder without the hub/ account id.
If you had a urn of at least 1 folder, this could have helped by using https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-parent-GET/
